# Floating issue with multiple images inside one p tag

Tags: css, wordpress, css-float

http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/downloads-2

Thanks to WP formatting, the images with captions sit in their own divs, whilst the others are all within a single `<p>` tag.

What I would like is for all the images, with or without captions, to flow nicely.

For now I have:

HTML - which I can't change:

```
<div style="width: 250px" class="wp-caption alignnone" id="attachment_158">
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/WaihauBay.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="159" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/WaihauBay-240x159.jpg" title="WaihauBay" class="size-medium wp-image-158 ">
  </a>
  <p class="wp-caption-text">
    Caption text goes here
  </p>
</div>
<p>
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/1011.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="160" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/1011-240x160.jpg" title="1011" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-162">
  </a>
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/1062.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="159" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/1062-240x159.jpg" title="1062" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-164">
  </a>
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/1064.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="160" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/1064-240x160.jpg" title="1064" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-166">
  </a>
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/521.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="160" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/521-240x160.jpg" title="521" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-168">
  </a>
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/519.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="160" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/519-240x160.jpg" title="519" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-170">
  </a>
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/507.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="360" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/507-240x360.jpg" title="507" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-171">
  </a>
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/508.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="360" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/508-240x360.jpg" title="508" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-172">
  </a>
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/BOY_1.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="159" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/BOY_1-240x159.jpg" title="BOY_1" class=" alignnone">
  </a>
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/BOY_3.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="311" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/BOY_3-240x311.jpg" title="BOY_3">
  </a>
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/BOY_2.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="158" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/BOY_2-240x158.jpg" title="BOY_2" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-175">
  </a>
  <a href="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/BOY_5.jpg">
    <img width="240" height="160" alt="" src="http://boythemovie.co.nz/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/BOY_5-240x160.jpg" title="BOY_5" class="alignnone size-medium wp-image-177">
  </a>
</p>
```

CSS:

```
.wp-caption {
    float: left;
}
#content img {
    float: left;
}
```

Any help in understanding how floated elements work in this case would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Floated elements should normally be used to wrap text around a certain element, for instance, your image. From my estimates of your question, you are trying to position caption for an image so that the position of other images are not disturbed.

Why not use the `display:inline-block` property. In that manner you can have plenty of such parent `div` enclosing n number of elements without affecting the position of elements outside this `div` 
It can be summarized as follows.

```
<div id="theGlobalDiv">

    <div id="withCaption" style="display:inline-block" >

       <img src="image.jpeg" />

      <p id="caption">Some caption inserted here</p>

  </div>

   <div id="withoutCaption" style="display:inline-block" >

     <img src="image2.jpeg" />

   </div>

</div>
```

Hence, `display:inline-block` will display `withCaption` and `withoutCaption` in one line but the elements inside them will be on successsive lines. **NOTE** that inline-block works *only* when elements using this property are inside another block level element. Hence, if you try to enclose `div` inside a `p` or two or more divs as ultimate parent elements, set to this property, then it will fail to achieve the desired flow

Comment: Thanks! But I'm afraid that I can't really edit the HTML, as that is how Wordpress outputs it. Is there anyway to make the page work just editing the CSS?